# Integrating Farseer Engine into an XNA game

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, wrapper, farseer

I have developed game simulation using C# and XNA 4.0. Right now it does not have any physical properties. I want to use Farseer Engine to assign physical properties to it, but without modifying the existing game code. So, is there a way to create a wrapper class of Farseer and use the farseer object to invoke the existing methods? (without modifying them)
If so how do I go about it?
Note: I am very new to both C# and XNA

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to create a wrapper around farseer. The cost of instantiating the world and creating bodies is something you want to do only once, really. It's further complicated by the fact that bodies only actually get added after the first world step.

It would, theoretically, be possible for you to use specific methods in farseer in isolation, but it's quite heavily coupled, and I think you'd find it a real uphill struggle.

Comment: I want to add the physical properties (especially collision) to the existing game objects. I think there should be some way to do that without writing the entire code seperately...

Comment: I've spent quite a bit of time working with Farseer, and all I can say is 'Good luck'. That code is *massively* complex, and if you can just snip out the bits you want, then that's good for you.